# Используя функции car и cdr необходимо извлечь из заданных списков элементы с указанными номерами

Tags: lisp

Используя функции car и cdr необходимо извлечь из заданных списков элементы с указанными номерами. В качестве результата выдайте список составленный из извлеченных элементов.
Списки: (G55 G66 G777), (9 (F G) I), (N I L T D J (II JJ)), Номера: 3, 2, 4.

```
(defun compose (w v z)
(compose '(g55 g66 g777) '(9 (f g) i) '(n i l t d j (ii jj)))
  (append (list (car w) (cadr w)
                (car v) (caddr v)
                (car z) (cadr z) (caddr z))
          (cddddr z)))
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

Error: execute: unbound symbol: "z" []

Comment: Почему вы задачу вызова `compose` впихнули в её определение ? Как вы её вызывали тогда? Это секретная рекурсия? Попробуйте вызов задачи сделать отдельно от определения функции.

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал в [Emacs Lisp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs_Lisp).

У меня (после нескольких попыток понять, как эта штука (язык Lisp)  все же работает -)) получилось следующее:

```
(defun compose (w v z)
  (list (cadr (cdr w)) (cadr v) (cadr (cddr z))))^J
compose
; тест на 3-х списках с пронумерованными элементами
(compose '(11 12 13) '(21 22 23) '(31 32 33 34 35))^J
(13 22 34)
; ваш пример входных данных
(compose '(g55 g66 g777) '(9 (f g) i) '(n i l t d j (ii jj)))^J
(g777 (f g) t)
```

`^J` это `Ctrl-J` -- "команда" для исполнения лиспового выражения в буфере `*scratch*` редактора Emacs